# Ionic/AngularJS - global modal with controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Bear with me - I'm an AngularJS newb.

I have a form that I want to be available from anywhere in my app, and I'm trying to figure out how to code that.  My current attempt is to put the modal into a service, like this:

```
.service('NewObjectService', function() {
  var svc = this;

  svc.showModal = function() {
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('template.html', {
      scope: null, // what should I do here?
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      svc.modal = modal;
      modal.show();
    });
  }
})

.controller('NewObjectController', function() {
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    console.log('NewObjectController');
    // setup new object
  })
})
```

Then from anywhere in my app, I can call `NewObjectService.showModal()` and the modal pops up.  That part is working.

The trouble I'm running into is that I can't get my controller to fire, so the initialization never gets called and my new object is null.

It seems like I should actually be calling the modal from within `NewObjectController` to setup scope, but I tried that and I couldn't figure out how to call that controller from within other controllers - hence the service.

I know I'm just doing something fundamentally wrong, but I'm not sure what it is.  Any help?

Update: I also just tried calling one controller from another using a root scope broadcast:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  this.showModal = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('new_object:show_modal');
  }
})

.controller('NewObjectCtrl', function() {
  $rootScope.$on('new_object:show_modal', function() {
    // show modal
  })
})
```

The problem I'm running into there is that NewObjectCtrl hasn't been invoked at the time MainCtrl runs, so it doesn't catch the broadcast event.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618213/how-to-reuse-one-controller-for-2-different-views) could help

Comment: That seems like a different problem than I'm dealing with.  I'm not trying to share a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a service you need to return itself in the Angular declaration ie var svc = {}; return svc; Call svc.showModal from any controller after you've injected the service and pass in the scope. Call the controller from another controller by using $rootScope.$on (receiver) and $rootScope.$emit (from)

```
.service('NewObjectService', function($ionicModal) {
  var svc = {};

  svc.showModal = function(_scope) {
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('template.html', {
      scope: _scope, // passing in scope from controller
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      svc.modal = modal;
      modal.show();
    });
  }

  return svc;

})

.controller('NewObjectController', function($scope, $rootScope, NewObjectService) {
  // fires off when $rootScope.$emit('ShowModal') is called anywhere
  $rootScope.$on('ShowModal', function(data) {
    NewObjectService.showModal(data._scope);
  });
})

.controller('OtherController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.contactOtherController = function() {
    // contact the other controller from this controller
    $rootScope.$emit("ShowModal", {scope: $scope});
  }
})
```

Comment: Ok, but your code will load the modal when `NewObjectController` is loaded - how do I trigger that from another controller?

Comment: I edited the code so you can use $rootScope.$on and $rootScope.$emit to communicate between controllers